# Block First Post and Late Answer reviews when you can’t flag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, flags

The First Posts queue has 4 actions:

> - Vote up or down to rate the question's quality and usefulness.
> - Edit to improve the question's appearance or clarity.
> - Comment to leave constructive feedback for the author, or vote up existing comments.
> - Flag to notify the moderators of serious problems

If you come across a spam post, you should flag. If you have no flags, these review queues should be disabled so people who can flag can review the items properly. Just like when you have no votes, you can’t access these queues as you can’t take appropriate action, the same thing should apply to flags.

Currently, this is not the case:

[image]

This applies to all sites, and should be disabled.